# Undefined variable on get_or_create in django?

Tags: python, django, relational-database

I have a many-to-many relationship between a link and a term in Django, but when trying to check if the relationship already exists between the link and term I'm getting an undefined variable on the method.

```
def create_models(my_term, link):
    obj, created = WikifyProjectTerms.objects.get_or_create(term = my_term)
```

With my models as:

```
class WikifyProjectTerms(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
    term = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class WikifyProjectLinks(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
    links = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class WikifyProjectLinksTerms(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
    links = models.ForeignKey(WikifyProjectLinks)
    terms = models.ForeignKey('WikifyProjectTerms')
```

I have pasted the line from the django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create (and tailored it) but Eclipse is insisting it does not exist, for any of my models. The `update_or_create()` method doesn't exist either.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

This isn't a runtime error, this is Eclipse complaining:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: But `WikifyProjectLinksTerms` indeed doesn't have `term` or `link` attributes...

Comment: I forgot to change that from trying with another model. It's not the attributes that don't exist, it's the method from Model.objects

Comment: It's impossible to tell what is causing the error here. That's why you should post *the actual error message* and the traceback.

Comment: There is no actual message, like a stacktrace. I've included a screenshot of what Eclipse is complaining about. As far as it goes the code won't run.

Answer (score 2):

Python, as I've had occasion to say once or twice before, is not Java.

One of things that makes it not-Java is that class attributes are defined dynamically. It is not always possible to determine what attributes an object has except at run-time.

Eclipse, or any other IDE that attempts to do static analysis of your code, is *not reliable* as a guide to what attributes do or do not exist on a class.

That's why many Python programmers prefer a simpler text editor - from vim to SublimeText - rather than an IDE. Don't forget, you have the Python shell which you can use to explore objects, using for example the `dir()` command, which will show you what an object actually has rather than what an IDE thinks it has.